# TortoiseCVS client or similar GUI that runs on Windows 11?

Tags: version-control, windows-11

I need to browse a CVS repository on a Windows 11 machine.  Normally I'd use [TortoiseCVS](http://www.tortoisecvs.org/), but this does not seem to be functional on Windows 11.

I have been directed to [CVS Suite](https://www.march-hare.com/cvspro/), but this seems to be a full-blown CVS installation and I only need a repo browser.

What would you recommend as a GUI for browsing a CVS repository on Windows 11?

Comment: Is it an CVS repo that is still in use or just something that had been archived? If it is the latter I would try to convert it to SVN or GIT, as the number of tools available for both is way better.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the suggestion! Let me check that option.